# Python. Function testing using Nose

Tags: python, automation, nose

I have just begun learning Python and I got stuck (1day experience :)). Couldn't you help me with my homework?

*Exercise:* 
We have module **checkers** with function **is_triangle**

The method signature with a documentation string:

```
def is_triangle(a, b, c):

   """

   :param a: length of first side

   :param b: length of second side

   :param c: length of third side

   :return: "True" if possible to create triangle with these sides. Otherwise "False"

   """
```

You should develop full set of tests that will verify this function.
The solution should use the nosetest library and it should be carried out in one file like:

$ Python% your_file_name% .py

What should I write in this .py file?

Comment: What do you think it means to be a triangle? You should have at least attempted this before asking.

Comment: come up with values for `a`, `b`, and `c` that should cause `is_triangle` to return `True`.  then come up with values for `a`, `b`, and `c` that should cause `is_triangle` to return `False`.  write a test function that tests that these values produce the appropriate results.  then add code to your function `is_triangle` such that it actually produces the desired results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this `.py` file you should write

```
import nose.tools as nt

from checkers import is_triangle


def test_is_triangle():
    # Define test_a, test_b, and test_c here such that they should produce a
    # return value of False.
    nt.assert_false(is_triangle(test_a, test_b, test_c))

    # Redefine test_a, test_b, and test_c here such that they should produce a
    # return value of True.
    nt.assert_true(is_triangle(test_a, test_b, test_c))
```

You should then run this script in one of two ways:

```
$ nosetests your_file_name.py
```

or

```
$ python your_file_name.py  # as your instructor has requested.
```

The test should fail until you have a properly written `is_triangle` function.  If you find that your initial tests are inadequate -- such that the tests pass even though `is_triangle` is incorrect -- add more.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\checkers_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from checkers import is_triangle
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\checkers.py", line 15
    $ nosetests your_file_name.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntaxC:\Python27

Comment: have you added any code to `is_triangle`?  you can't have a function with no code.  at the least you need to add `pass`.

Comment: I have two .py files: checkers.py and checkers_test.py

Comment: checkers.py has:                                                                                           def is_triangle(a, b, c):
   pass
   """

   :param a: length of first side

   :param b: length of second side

   :param c: length of third side

   :return: "True" if possible to create triangle with these sides. Otherwise "False"

   """

Comment: What should I write in checkers_test.py? Couldn't you write it to give me an example. I can't understand the sequencing at all :( I need an example with instruction how to run it. Pleasee

Comment: `pass` should come after the docstring.  what do you mean you "can't understand the sequencing at all"?  i'm happy to answer specific questions, but right now it sounds to me like you're asking for someone to do your homework for you.  if i were to give you all the code, you wouldn't learn very much, would you?

Comment: and what you should write in `checkers_test` is what i wrote in my answer.